# Can a text attribute be set on .mp4 files that could be used for version info?

Tags: video, mp4, chm

I have a number of mp4 training videos that I use as help files with our software suite.  I do not want to disrupt the naming convention of the video because that would change links all over the place, but would rather like to be able to tag the video with a version number for configuration management.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the version information in the file metadata, for example, in the `Comments` property.

[image: MP4 file properties > Details > Comments]